# Cross-platform (microcontroller-PC) algorithm development

Tags: c, network-programming, cross-platform, microcontroller

I was asked to develop a algorithm for network application on C. This project will be developed on Linux for PC and then it will be transferred to a more portable platform, something that will include a microcontroller. There are many microcontroller/companies out there that provide very nice and large libraries for TCP/IP. This software will hold statistics on the network performance.

The whole idea of a cross platform (uC - PC) seems rubbish to me cause eventually the code should be written in a more platform specific way for the microcontroller, but I am not expert to judge anyway.

Is there any clever way of doing this or is there a anyone that did this before? My brainstorming has "Wrapper library" and "Matlab"... Any ideas?

Thx!

Comment: Is the Linux version part of the required 'end-product', or is it just seen as a stepping stone to the microcontroller-based version?

Answer (score 1):

I do agree with you to some extent - you do want the target system and the system on which you are developing in the interim should be as close as possible (it is better if they can match). Nevertheless the idea with cross-platform is to get you started with the firmware development while the hardware is being designed. Instead of doing it on Linux - what I would do is to use Embedded OS simulator. Here are the steps
- Step 1: Identify the OS for the Embedded System; make sure that OS has a simulator that runs on PC (Win or Linux)  Typical Embedded OS with Simulator include VxWorks, μC/OS-II, QNX, uClinux ...  Agreeing on the OS means that the hardware design team knows that the OS is the right match for the hardware that is being designed and there is a consensus that the hardware + OS + Application being designed will meet the requirements of the system that is being developed.
- Step 2: Use this simulator to develop the application until the hardware that is being designed is brought up.
- Step 3: Once the first version of the hardware is ready and has been powered up - you can run your application with minimum changes - mostly likely no changes to the code, but changes to the linker/library being used is likely.

The idea of cross-platform if done correct has immense advantages - it helps remove serializing your project development activities.

Given that you mention it is a TCP/IP application - check for Berkeley Sockets support and you use it. Usually this API should not matter if you are using a Simulator, in the extreme case if you have to change the OS for whatever reason your Berkeley Sockets based application is likely to be better portable.

Answer (score 1):

Just assume you can use the standard BSD socket library (system calls are socket(), bind(), accept(), connect(), recv(), send(), with various options).  Any OS with a TCP/IP stack will support this standard API.

There may be some caveats that you will run into if your embedded system uses a run to completion type TCP/IP stack like *u*IP, but those will be easily solvable.

Also only use POSIX file I/O (fopen, fread, fwrite, printf, etc).  But keep in mind your target may not have a filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

If using a simulator was not an option I would try to wrap the Linux functions up in interfaces that match those of the embedded system, if possible.  That way any extra bulk in the system will be on the Linux development system (which is not resource constrained).  Various embedded OSes and TCP/IP stacks can have vastly different architectures, so how easy this is can range from nearly impossible to no work at all.

If it turns out that writing wrapper libraries to make Linux look like the embedded system is too difficult then I suggest at least trying to keep the embedded OS in mind while writing the Linux version so that you can try to at least write some functions so that they work on both systems.

If it doesn't take too long writing a Linux version of at least part of the code may help you to shake out a few flaws in the overall design, at the very least.  At most it will allow you to more quickly test changes to the system since loading code onto an embedded device often takes more time than you would like.  It may also be easier to debug on your development machine.

Some embedded OSes will run on x86, and it would not surprise me if some of them have drivers that allow them to be run in virtual machines, so this may be an option as well.

Another thing to consider is the endian-ness and the word size of the development machine verses the embedded system.  If these differ then you need to keep this in mind as you code.  Getting this type of thing right when you originally write the code is easier than going back and trying to fix code, in my opinion.